# Drawing smoke effects with java

Tags: java, java-2d

Is there any way to draw a smoke effect in java (by using Java2D API). I want to achieve this: when a user provides the color for the smoke, the program automatically draws a smoke effect with that color. How could I do this?

Comment: If you can figure a way to do it in any language, it can be done in Java.

Answer (score 9):

The terminology used in computer graphics is particle systems, and not smoke effect. After all, you can model smoke by treating it as a collection of several particles.

There are quite a few tutorials that discuss building particle systems in Java. Both of the links listed below have source code:

- [Particle Systems](http://www.shiffman.net/teaching/nature/particles/), by Daniel Shiffman.
- [Particle Systems in Java](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/particles.html), by Jerry Huxtable.

**Related question on Stackoverflow:**

1. [2D smoke/fire/mist algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151807/2d-smoke-fire-mist-algorithm)

Comment: Particle systems is only one way to create a smoke effect, which is very good for animations. For static images, there are other ways, like fractal clouds. It really depends on what do you want to achieve.